# Position relative and absolute

Tags: html, css

I have DIV container with relative position, and the child with absolute position.
here is my code source:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jt92sedr/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper h1 {
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}
```

when I put in top 60px, the child element jump to the bottom , normally the container has a relative position so the child element should be under the container not over the container.

Please, someone can explain me why this happen ?
I hope I explained,  well my question.

Comment: "should be under" - Which dimension are we talking about?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: `top: 60px` means that it is `60px` below the top of the parent. If you want it to be `60px` below the bottom of the parent, use `bottom: -60px`.

Comment: **always** include a normalize / reset css!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an element with `position: absolute` that element is placed relatively to its closest **positioned** parent. A **positioned** element is any element with `position` different from `static`, be it `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

In your case you have a `.wrapper` with `position: relative` and `h1` inside it with `position: absolute`, that is why the latter is positioned 60 pixels from the top of its parent.

If you insist of the child element being below the parent, add `z-index: -1` to it - http://jsfiddle.net/jt92sedr/4/
This property applies only to **positioned** elements.

You can check: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: A relatively positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position. The absolutely positioned element is relative to the first parent container that has absolute or relative positioning. In your case, putting position: absolute and top: 60px to the child element will move it 60px from the top of the relatively positioned parent element.

There is a great article here https://kolosek.com/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute explaining the relative and absolute positions in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is actually doing what you think (sort of), but there is also (in Firefox, at least) a 21 pixel top margin which pushes the "text" down a bit farther.

Add a rule to remove the top margin:

```
.wrapper h1 {
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0; /* added this */
    top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: but if I set the top to 100px : http://jsfiddle.net/jt92sedr/5/
still not working

Comment: Absolute positioning is relative to the closest positioned parent. So, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "margin:0; to the h1 element:

```
.wrapper h1 {
color: #333;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
margin:0;
display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way around, Relative always means relative to the parent. if you want to the child to be set in relation to parent, then make it relative.

the relative in your case on parent does not mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering why 60px from top of the div looks like 80px or 90 px? If this is your question, answer is easy. Browsers add some margin to h1, div and body elements. Simply clear that efect:

```
body, div, h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/14sLb8jg/

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers, like Chrome and Firefox, are putting a 0.67em margin on top and bottom of h1 tags.

In your case declaring a margin 0 for .wrapper h1 will solve your problem.

Your code should be:

```
.wrapper {
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
} 

.wrapper h1 {
color: #333;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
margin: 0;
}
```

---

If you are in doubt, use your browser's inspection / developer tools to find out what default stylings the browser is giving into any given element so you know which one you need to override.

---

#### Jsfiddle Example

[View on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8ahw1ba/)